# Can my LED fan light that's hardwired to a dimmer switch also be controlled, ON/OFF, by the remote it came with?

Tags: lighting, ceiling-fan, led, dimmer-switch

I have two switches set up for our LED remote fan.

1st switch: to power on the unit, which still allows me to change the speed settings on the remote.

2nd dimmer switch: to power the lights, but, the remote doesn't turn my fan light ON / OFF, even when the dimmer switch is on at its lowest setting.

Comment: Can you post photos of the insides of all boxes involved please?

Comment: Wall mounted dimmer switches often have compatibility issues with LED fan lights. Remote control fans usually have only one wall switch to power the fan and the light. Does yours have two wall switches (fan & light) plus the remote?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. I'm guessing the chopped power supplied by a dimmer will confuse the remote control. And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know you'll know the details of contributing here.

Comment: What make and model is said fan?  Can you post photos of the boxes involved?  Also, what make and model is the dimmer switch in question?

Comment: Also, is replacing the dimmer/fan remote with a different product in the cards?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer that helped you the most, or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer

Answer (score 1):

With a fan + remote, you have two chocices:  Wire it so fan+light are controlled by remote, and ou can't use a dimmer. (can't dim the fan).  Or, have fan controlled by remote and light controlled by switch, which can be a dimmer if it doesn't affect the fan.

### Code requires a light switch in a room *that works*

You may have noticed that when you go into almost any room anywhere, your arm knows exactly where to look for the light switch.  That's no accident; it's carefully enforced.

So the wall switch has to control **something**.  If the fan light were the only option, then the electrician would have to have chosen the "light by switch, fan by remote" option.

There is no way to have it both ways.  Especially not with a pre-existing dimmer; that's not possible in any way whatsoever.  **These things simply will not play together**.  They are incompatible.  Careful selection of control module, wall switch and remote, from a single product line designed to do that, may be possible.